# i can not understand why not use JSONObject.wrap

Tags: java, android, json

i have change minSdkVersion to 21, but when i use JSONObject.wrap,it fatal by No static method wrap(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, we can confirm 2 things:

1. Java class obfuscation is enabled in your build
2. The class `org.json.JSONObject` that is being used is NOT the one from `android.jar`

You can run the following command to find where it comes from:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath
```

The output may look like below:

```
+--- com.sample.infra.galaxy:galaxy-fds-sdk-java:3.0.9
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2 -> 4.4.13
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 -> 1.2
|    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 31.0.1-android (*)
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.1
|    \--- com.sample.infra.galaxy:galaxy-fds-core:3.0.9
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 31.0.1-android (*)
|         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|         +--- org.json:json:20090211
|         \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
```

and you can see that `org.json:json:20090211` is used in this project, and the class `JSONObject` in this library may not have `#wrap` API, though the class `JSONObject` in `android.jar` has such API, it won't be used at runtime.